# Rendering UIiView content to match resolution of another image

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview

OK, this set up is a little complicated, let me see if I can explain it correctly.

I have a UIView -> BackgroundImageView -> ContainerView -> SmallerImageView

I have a full resolution (higher res then native screen) image loaded into the UIimageView. I have an "overlay" image in the SmallerImageview.  The user is allowed to adjust the location of the smaller image by dragging around on the screen.

I want to create an image of the same resolution as the background image, that contains only the object from the SmallerImageView. Like expanding the "Canvas size" of the image, but leaving the content in the same relative position. I do this by "rendering" the container view, which contains the subview.

I currently use the following to create an image from the ContainerView

```
- (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view {
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size,view.opaque,2);
     [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

     return img;
}
```

The problem is that the container view is 320x568 (screen size) and the background image is 960x1280 (pixel resolution). They are different aspect rations, and there isn't a single scaling factor in the call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` that I can use to make the two sizes match up.

_mike

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that you want an image the same size as `backgroundImageView.image.size`? Why are you passing the other view's size to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`?

Comment: Yes, I want it the same size as the backgroundImageView. I'm not using that view because I don't want the background image in the new image, just the smaller image, with a transparent background. Like Photoshop layers. I have a layer on top of my base image that has other graphic elements. I want to be able to render just the top view as a separate image. I was using this "container view" as a proxy to get me something that is the correct size, but it's ratio isn a't the same as the image. I know, super confusing. I have a feeling I'm over-thinking this.......

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking correctly (which is a big if), this should do what you want:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)smallerView container:(UIView *)biggerView {
    // Create the image context the size you want it. The scale determines if
    // it's a "retina" image or not. Use 0 so it does the right thing on the
    // right devices.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(biggerView.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // When you call [view renderInContext:], it renders it as if the top left
    // of the context you're rendering is the view's bounds.origin (usually
    // CGPointZero, but it can be different for views like UIScrollView. To
    // get around that, we have to figure out what the "top left" we want is.

    // First we find out how far our view's top left corner is offset from
    // the "big" view's top left corner. If we just used smallerView.frame.origin
    // without transforming it, it would be relative to the container view, which
    // isn't what we want.
    CGPoint topLeft = [biggerView convertPoint:smallerView.frame.origin fromView:smallerView.superview];

    // This offsets all subsequent drawing operations by the amount we
    // calculated.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(c, topLeft.x, topLeft.y);

    // Now we render the view at the right location.
    [smallerView.layer renderInContext:c];

    // Normal stuff
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Invoke that with `imageWithView:(UIView *)smallerImageView container:backgroundImageView` and it should do what you want.

Comment: Lemme play around with this a bit. I'm still not sure I even understand the question I am asking :-) Your recommendation gives me some more things to chew on though.  Thanks.